# Can't connect to my tomcat 8 websocket

Tags: java, tomcat, websocket

I have written a client program that connects to my websocket on the server. I set up tomcat8 with the examples working and hit the EchoAnnotation endpoint with my client program.

I wrote this endpoint program as follows:

```
@ServerEndpoint(value = "/websocket")
public class PortServer implements AirMessageListener {

public PortServer() { }

@OnOpen
public void start(Session session) {
        //do stuff
}

@OnClose
public void end() {
        //do stuff
}
}

@OnMessage
public void incoming(String message) {
        //do stuff
}

@OnError
public void onError(Throwable tw) throws Throwable {
        //do stuff
}
```

I compile this and create a war file called portserver and drop it into my tomcat webapps directory. I then switched my client program from connecting to: `ws://localhost:8080/examples/websocket/echoAnnotation` to `ws://localhost:8080/portserver/websocket` and run it. I get:

```
Connecting to:ws://localhost:8080/portserver/websocket
Exception in thread "main" com.corrisoft.air.exception.AirException: Error connecting to server
    at com.corrisoft.air.socket.AirSocketClient.<init>(AirSocketClient.java:60)
    at test.corrisoft.air.portserver.SocketConversation.<init>(SocketConversation.java:46)
    at test.corrisoft.air.portserver.RunPortServerTester.initConfigProperties(RunPortServerTester.java:76)
    at test.corrisoft.air.portserver.RunPortServerTester.<init>(RunPortServerTester.java:34)
    at test.corrisoft.air.portserver.RunPortServerTester.main(RunPortServerTester.java:109)
Caused by: javax.websocket.DeploymentException: Handshake error.
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.client.ClientManager$1$1.run(ClientManager.java:466)
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.client.ClientManager$1.run(ClientManager.java:502)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.client.ClientManager$SameThreadExecutorService.execute(ClientManager.java:654)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.client.ClientManager.connectToServer(ClientManager.java:359)
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.client.ClientManager.connectToServer(ClientManager.java:195)
    at com.corrisoft.air.socket.AirSocketClient.<init>(AirSocketClient.java:58)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: org.glassfish.tyrus.core.HandshakeException: Response code was not 101: 404.
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.core.Handshake.validateServerResponse(Handshake.java:279)
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.client.TyrusClientEngine.processResponse(TyrusClientEngine.java:138)
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.container.grizzly.client.GrizzlyClientFilter.handleHandshake(GrizzlyClientFilter.java:318)
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.container.grizzly.client.GrizzlyClientFilter.handleRead(GrizzlyClientFilter.java:288)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:209)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:550)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

I placed an index.html inside my portserver app and can hit: `http://localhost:8080/portserver` just fine, which means the directories are OK. I then verified that my class was in my WEB-INF/classes directory.

I looked at the examples and found the ExamplesConfig class that I thought might be a "magic" class that enables the endpoints, so I implemented my own and and stuck in the jar file.

```
/**
 * 
 */
package com.corrisoft.air.portserver;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.websocket.Endpoint;
import javax.websocket.server.ServerApplicationConfig;
import javax.websocket.server.ServerEndpointConfig;

/**
 * @author Corrisoft Android Development
 */
public class WebSocketConfig implements ServerApplicationConfig {

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see javax.websocket.server.ServerApplicationConfig#getAnnotatedEndpointClasses(java.util.Set)
     */
    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getAnnotatedEndpointClasses(Set<Class<?>> scanned) {
        // Deploy all WebSocket endpoints defined by annotations in the
        // web application. Filter out all others to avoid issues when running
        // tests on Gump
        Set<Class<?>> results = new HashSet<>();
        for (Class<?> clazz : scanned) {
            if (clazz.getPackage().getName().startsWith("com.corrisoft.air")) {
                System.out.println("Adding endpoint for:" + clazz.getName());
                results.add(clazz);
            }
        }
        return results;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see javax.websocket.server.ServerApplicationConfig#getEndpointConfigs(java.util.Set)
     */
    @Override
    public Set<ServerEndpointConfig> getEndpointConfigs( Set<Class<? extends Endpoint>> scanned) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

It does not seem to be running this class.

Is there some configuration I missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that the problem was that one of my dependent classes was missing from the classpath. Tomcat 8, under these circumstances, doesn't add the endpoint and doesn't throw an exception into the log.

I deployed the same war file to tomcat 7 and got an exception. Worked the classpath until it was good and then deployed back to tomcat 8 where it is now working.

I created defect 56442 here: https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=56442 for tomcat eating the exception instead of displaying in the log.

Comment: For anyone else plagued by this; take a CLOSE look at your URL.  I was piecing my url together, based on a configuration file.  I missed a single "/" character when constructing the URL, and was convinced that it was correct!  If you do stuff like the following, I suggest, printing out the "constructed URL" and studying that closely before chasing your tale:

Comment: @Darrin if you found this helpful, please upvote the question and/or the answer.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else plagued by this; take a CLOSE look at your URI.  I was piecing my url together, based on a configuration file.  I missed a single "/" character when constructing the URL, and was convinced that it was correct!  If you do stuff like the following, I suggest, printing out the "constructed URL" and studying that closely before chasing your tail:

```
public static final String WEBSOCKETHOST = "localhost";         // TODO: Get from configuration
public static final int WEBSOCKETPORT = 10080;                  // TODO: Get from configuration
public static final String WEBSOCKETSERVERROOT = "/sceagents";  // TODO: Get from configuration
public static final String WEBSOCKETSERVERENDPOINT = "neo";     // TODO: Get from configuration
public static final String WEBSOCKETPROTOCOL = "ws";            // TODO: Get from configuration

String uri = WEBSOCKETPROTOCOL + "://" + WEBSOCKETHOST + ":" + Integer.toString(WEBSOCKETPORT) + WEBSOCKETSERVERROOT + "/" + WEBSOCKETSERVERENDPOINT;
```